# csv output from excel error but other data types work correctly?

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv

Ok I am attempting to write a Macro that saves an excel Workbook into a csv file. I have tried many different solutions but I am still having issues getting the values to print properly. when I open the file it produces. The rest of the code I left out all it does is takes the original spreadsheet and copys the contents into a temporary sheet so I can take multiple sheets from the same WB and print them to the same csv file. it also has a module that will clear all formatting and contents of that temporary file. I ran the code to just print it to a new excel spreadsheet and it worked fine just will not print to a csv not sure why

out put looks like this:

```
K     ! bîh^     [Content_Types].xml ¢(
[… skip a bunch of binary lines …]
KÆ8k¡~¥-ÙÔäá ûÜ
```

My code looks like this:

```
Sub SaveFile()
Dim NewName As String
Dim nm As Name
Dim ws As Worksheet

If MsgBox("Copy specific sheets to a new workbook" & vbCr & _
"New sheets will be pasted as values, named ranges removed" _
, vbYesNo, "NewCopy") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False

     '       Copy specific sheets
     '       *SET THE SHEET NAMES TO COPY BELOW*
     '       Array("Sheet Name", "Another sheet name", "And Another"))
     '       Sheet names go inside quotes, seperated by commas
    On Error GoTo ErrCatcher
    Sheets(Array("Raw Data Copy")).copy
    On Error GoTo 0

     '       Paste sheets as values
     '       Remove External Links, Hperlinks and hard-code formulas
     '       Make sure A1 is selected on all sheets
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Cells.copy
        ws.[A1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Cells(1, 1).Select
        ws.Activate
    Next ws
    Cells(1, 1).Select

     '       Remove named ranges
    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        nm.Delete
    Next nm

     '       Input box to name new file
    NewName = "test"

     '       Save it with the NewName and in the same directory as original
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & NewName & ".csv"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Exit Sub

ErrCatcher:
MsgBox "Specified sheets do not exist within this workbook"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

SaveCopyAs only saves an Excel Workbook in Excel format.  Even if you append .csv to your filename, the file is still an .xls formatted file.

The Workbook SaveAs method lets you to specify the type of file you want to save to.

However, if you use the SaveAs method, it changes the name of your current file.

This earlier question on Stack Overflow has some options on how to use the SaveAs method without changing the name of the file you are working on.

[Why does VBA ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs change the open spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483725/why-does-vba-activeworkbook-saveas-change-the-open-spreadsheet) has some comments on how to properly use the SaveAs method and not have the name of your current file changed in the process.

Comment: If I use the SaveAs method can I save the location to a etl  server or does it have to be local?